# Comparing the filenames with an integer and reading the filename that is less than the integer

Tags: bash, unix

I'm writing a script to read through a folder and compare the file names with a variable.

Both the file name and variable have time as strings as their value.

Ed: filename - 131222 variable = 133000

My folder contains a list of files with similar naming convention, in increasing time order. My variable would fall between any of the two file names. I need to identify the file which is most likely closer(lesser) to the variable.

I'm using bash shell scripting.

How can i do this comparison? I'm using a for loop to iteratively read the filenames in a folder. But i'm clueless on how to do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `expr` ...

```
filename="123"
ToCompare=100
cmp=`expr $filename - $ToCompare`
if [ $cmp -lt 0 ] ; then
    #file has lower value
else
    #file has higher value

fi
```

Comment: `else  # file has higher *or equal* value`. @user2759260 Are you sure that the target number will never be *equal to* a filename? If it might be, use `-le` rather than `-lt`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that all of the files in a directory have only numbers in the filenames, then this is going to work:

```
need=200 # we're looking for a file that is closest to 200
ls -1 | sort -n | awk "{if(\$1 > $need && prev != \"\") {print ($need-prev < \$1-$need) ? prev : \$1; x=1; exit} prev=\$1} END{if (x != 1) print prev}"
```

#### But I highly recommend this one(because it has a bonus filename check!):

```
#!/bin/bash

need=500

shopt -s nullglob # just in case there are no files at all

for curFile in *; do
    if ! [[ $curFile =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then # if there are files that have other symbols besides numbers
        echo "Wrong filename format: $curFile"
        continue
    fi

    (( curFile <= need )) && ( ((need - curFile < need - smaller )) || [[ -z $smaller ]] ) && smaller=$curFile
    (( curFile >= need )) && ( ((curFile - need < higher - need )) || [[ -z $higher ]] ) && higher=$curFile
done

if [[ -n $smaller ]] && (( need - smaller < higher - need )) || [[ -z $higher ]]; then
    echo "$smaller"
else
    echo "${higher}"
fi
```

If you have two files with similar distance (for example `10` and `20` and you're searching for `15`) it will output higher number.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand...

Use two `for` cycles, in the first determine the closer file. In the second `for` choose the file whose "closeness" equals the closer file determined in the first `for`.

```
min=1000000000
var=131119

for file in $(ls -1)
do
    if [ $var -le $file ]
    then
        diff=$(($file - $var))
        if [ $diff -lt $min ]; then min=$diff; fi
        echo "$file - $var = $(($file - $var))"
    fi
done

echo $min

for file in $(ls -1)
do
    if [ $var -le $file ]
    then
        diff=$(($file - $var))
        if [ $min -eq $diff ]
        then
            echo "This is your file: $file"
        fi
    fi
done
```

A lot of code, though.